# Two isomorphisms of the space of vector fields/forms

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, vector-bundles, vector-fields

Suppose you have a diffeomorphism

$$
\phi: M \to N.
$$

As far as I understand, this gives rise to two distinct isomorphisms

$$
a : \mathcal A^1(M) \cong \mathcal A^1(N) :b
$$

between the space of 1-forms on $M$, and on $N$. The two are given as follows:

Given a 1-form $\theta: M \to T^*M$, $a(\theta): N \to T^*N$ is defined to be the 1-form fitting into the commutative diagram below:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T^*M @>T^*\phi>\cong> T^*N \\
@A{\theta}AA @A{a(\theta)}AA\\
c @<\phi^{-1}<\cong< d
\end{CD}
$$

On the other hand, $b(\theta)$ is defined to be the usual pull-back of 1-forms, so that for any tangent vector $v \in TM$, we have
$$
b(\theta)(v) = \theta(D\phi(v))
$$
where $D\phi: TM \to TN$ is the derivative of $\phi$.

> Is there any relationship between these two isomorphisms? For instance, an equation in which both isomorphisms appear?

Dually, we could note that there are two isomorphisms
$$
c, e: \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(TN)
$$
where given any vector field $X: M \to TM$, $c(X)$ is defined to fit into the commutative diagram

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
TM @>T\phi>\cong> TN \\
@A{X}AA @A{c(X)}AA\\
c @<\phi^{-1}<\cong< d
\end{CD}
$$

and $e(X)$ is the usual pushforward of a vector field along its image: For any smooth function $f: N \to \mathbb R$, we have
$$
e(X)(f) = X(f \circ \phi).
$$

> Is there any relationship between $c$ and $e$?

Comment: In both diagrams, by $c$ and $d$ I assume you mean $M$ and $N$. If so, $a$ and $b$ are inverses of each other and $c$ and $e$ are the same. All you're doing is rephrasing the definitions of pullback and pushforward in terms of commutative diagrams.